# Not able to print a NSMutableArray in objective c ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
sortedWords = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[wordCounts allValues] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"count" ascending:FALSE]]]];

NSLog(@"%@",sortedWords);//sortedWords is an NSMutableArray
```

wordCounts is an `NSMutableDictionary` and count is an `integer` value

Comment: What do you mean "not able to print"? You code doesn't do the `NSLog`, as ignoring it or the value showed is wrong?

Comment: What is the output you get?

Comment: what is the actual problem ?. I just run your code. it's working..

Comment: You should split up that nasty 4-level nested set of calls into several lines so you can debug each step and see where the problem is.

Comment: Try `alloc init` sortedWords

Comment: @Stefan, actually `arrayWithArray:` is an class method that creates and returns an array.. so the `alloc init` is already done

Comment: i am getting this output in my console <WCWord: 0x8d84fd0>" for printing the sortedwords. and WCWord is a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use NSLog to print an object the way you did, it automatically prints the details it thinks are interesting to you about that object (in your case, the class name and the address). You want the content of the array's elements, in which case you should loop through the array and print each of the elements. For example, if your array contains NSStrings, you should do something like this:

```
for (NSString *curElement in sortedWords)
{
   NSLog(@"%@", curElement);
}
```

If your elements are custom objects or any other kind of object, you can, of course, format the NSLog accordingly.

Hope this helps...

**Edit:**

Following your comment, for your specific case, the loop would look something like this:

```
for (WCWord *curElement in sortedWords)
{
   // Assuming you want to print the 'count' property and it's int
   NSLog(@"%d", curElement.count);

   // You can, of course, use any other field (or several of them)
}
```

Comment: I did used the for loops for printing the array elements but it is still showing "<WCWord: 0x8d84fd0>" in my console.

Comment: Again, because when using NSLog, it gives you what it thinks is the most valuable info about the object. WCWord is a custom object, so either you directly access the property you wish to print (NSLog(@"%d", curElement.count), for example), or you change the description method to return something other than the class name and the address.

Comment: here sortedwords contains elements of datatype NSString, and WCWord is a Class. can you help me with the code for accessing the words in the sortedwords array?

Comment: this thing took 1 day but still not able to solve it.. pls help